# jqgrid re-initialization

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to find a way to modify grid parameters. Let me better explain the scenario. 
I have two jqGrid object on my page both calling a remote web service function that feeds the data. The first object is the main grid and when the user click on a button that is inside a column the application shows a dialog, with the second grid inside.

The second grid to shall contains some data that is related to a field contained in the first grid selected row. So the code I have actually is the following:

```
function showDialog(customerID, wsBaseUrl, sl) {
    var title = "";
    var dlg = $("#pclist");
    //Set the title with the value returned
    dlg.dialog("option", "title", title);
    createGrid(customerID, wsBaseUrl, sl);
    //Open the dialog
    dlg.dialog('open');
}

function createPCGrid(customerID, wsBaseUrl) {
    var pc_grid = $('#pcgrid');
    pc_grid.jqGrid({
        url: wsBaseUrl + 'GetOrderList',
        colNames: ['OrderID', 'Order Date', 'Qty', 'Unit', 'Line total'],
        colModel: [
            //omitted for brevity
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            id: "OrderID"
        },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
            if (postData.customerID === undefined) postData.customerID = customerID;
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        pager: $('#pcgrid_pager'),
        sortname: 'OrderID',
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: '280',
        rownumbers: true,
        gridview: true
    });
}
```

As you can see I am re-creating, each time a click has been done, a grid object and binding it's parameter `customerID` on the list of params that will be sent to the server by the grid in its `serializeGridData` function event.

Unfortunately this does not work and the initial param does never get changed.

Maybe I am not doing it correctly anyway. Is there any way to re-initialize the grid or to pass params to the grid to be serialized in its subsequent requests as in my sample?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that the dialog will be hidden and not destroyed after you close it. So you can include call of [$("#pcgrid").jqGrid('GridUnload')](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods#add_on_grid_methods) before assigning of `pc_grid = $('#pcgrid')`.

Comment: May help others. This does not work for 4.8.2. but this works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316701/uncaught-exception-jqgrid-no-such-method-gridunload