# uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: GridUnload

Tags: jqgrid

**THE PLAN**

I have a page with a jqGrid on it - this grid should be able to load one of three json payloads that are of the same type - just different filters. The data that loads is based on the button one clicks (In Planning, Approved, Completed).

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem I am having is when I reference *$("#jobGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');* I get an "uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: GridUnload".

**THE CODE**

The following libraries are loaded - basically I grabbed them all trying to get *$("#jobGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');* to fire

```
<!-- jqGrid Resources-->    
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script> 
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/src/grid.base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/src/grid.common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/src/grid.formedit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/src/jquery.fmatter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/src/grid.jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/plugins/grid.addons.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cdn.cov.com/jqGrid_JS_5.0.0/css/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
```

JavaScript function where exception occurs. Note: When this method is fired, data already exists in the grid

```
// Approved Filter
var approvedFilter = function () {
     // Ready Up Defaults
     $.jgrid.defaults.width = $("#jobGridContainer").width();
     $.jgrid.defaults.responsive = true;

     // Reset Data (Grid has data in it already
     $("#jobGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload'); 

     $("#jobGrid").jqGrid({
          url: RestService.GetApprovedJobsService(),
          mtype: "GET",
          styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
          datatype: "json",
          colModel: [
              { label: 'JobNumber', name: 'JobNumber', key: true, width: 75 },
              { label: 'Job Name', name: 'JobName', width: 150 },
              { label: 'Request State', name: 'JobState', width: 150 },
              { label: 'Status', name: 'JobStatus', width: 150 },
              { label: 'Request By', name: 'JobRequestor', width: 150 },
              { label: 'Last Modified', name: 'LastModifiedDate' }
          ],
          viewrecords: true,
          height: 375,
          rowNum: 10,
          loadonce: true,
          pager: "#jqGridPager",
          caption: "Showing Approved Requests. Click row to view details",
          onSelectRow: function (rowid, selected) {
              if (rowid != null) {
                  document.location.href = getAppRootUrl() + "/Service/Job/" + rowid;
              }
          }

     });
}
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9):

You use [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103532) which have some incompatibility with previous versions of jqGrid (see [the release notes](http://guriddo.net/?p=123585) of Guriddo jqGrid JS 4.8 for more information). Another fork of jqGrid - [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) don't have the problem with `GridUnload` method.

If you need to use `GridUnload` or `GridDestroy` in Guriddo jqGrid JS then you can't use more `$("#jobGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');`. Instead of that you should use

```js
$.jgrid.gridUnload("jobGrid"); // id of grid as parameter
```

Another common remark to your code. You included first `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and then `grid.base.js`, `grid.common.js` and other. It's wrong. `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` includes all the modules in minimized form. It's wrong to include the same modules multiple times.

Comment: Awesome Oleg! Thank you so much for the clarification... I will let you know how it goes and mark your response appropriately. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason Guriddo decided remove $("#gridid").jqGrid("GridUnload") from the new grid.  For us it created an upward compatibility issue, especially since the jQuery element is passed as a parameter. We have elected to just put it back using the following code on startup.

```
if ($.fn.jqGrid["GridUnload"] === undefined) {
    $.fn.jqGrid["GridUnload"] = $.jgrid.gridUnload;
}
```